# Ignore all fields and properties by default

Tags: c#, json

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to serialize my objects. I want that by default no field or property gets serialized, only if I decorate it with a `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]` Attribute. I couldn't find anything in the newtonsoft docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` attribute to your class, everything will be ignored unless you explicitly Opt-In by using a `[JsonProperty]` attribute.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string NotIgnored { get; set; }

    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    public string Line3 { get; set; }
}
```

More info here: [Newtonsoft Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOptIn.htm)

Comment: works, but it would be better if I could add an option to a JsonSerializerSettings object. Is this possible?

Comment: You can create a contract resolver if you wish, I'm assuming you are asking because you don't want to go back and mark all of your classes with this attribute?